# Why element does not replace in numpy.array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to assign a new value to [i + 1][j] of array, but it seems there is a problem.

```
a = np.array(['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#','#', ' ', ' ', 'A', ' ', '#',
 '#', ' ', '#', 'P', ' ', '#',
 '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#',
 '#', 'P', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#',
 '#', '2', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#',
 '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#'])

print(len(a))
b = np.reshape(a,(7,6))
i = 0
j = 0
print(b[i + 1][j])
b[i + 1][j] = 'AP'
print(b[i + 1][j])
```

output:

```
#
A
```

How can I assign "AP" instead of "#" ?

Comment: Why are you using `numpy` here? Why not just a regular list? Note, numpy uses a real arrays, so each element is a fixed size. When you initialized your array, the data-type here defaults to `dtype='<U1'`, so that means it accepts single unicode characters. Not, it's assigning just `"A"` not `"#"`, because it automatically truncates (perhaps it should throw an error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b.dtype` (see [data type objects](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)) is `<U1` which is a unicode string of length 1.

you could fix that with

```
a = np.array(['#',..., '#'], dtype='<U2')
```

which will then accept strings up to length 2.